# Only Allow Iphone to access REST webservice

Tags: java, rest

I was wondering if there is any way to restrict access to my REST webservices for non ios users. I am using Java and Jersey for my RESTful application.

The aim of this exercise is that since my webservice accepts POSTS of XML data, I would like to restrict the exchanges to an iphone client, to prevent manipulation of xml for security reasons.

the client side is an iphone application developed by us.

Comment: You could check the useragent. Of course, the useragent can be manipulated, but it provides at least a bit of restriction

Comment: Which application is using your webservices?

Comment: No. The TCP connection from the iPhone is no different than any other. Anything you receive via that connection as an "identifier" can be generated by any other device capable of making a TCP connection.

Comment: is there some kind of validation service, where we could check if the device token is an iphone ie the apple device id

Comment: can you install client certificates on the app?

Comment: @BrianRoach Post that as an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to make this restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(moved to answer from comment by request)

No.

The TCP connection from the iPhone is no different than any other. Anything you receive via that connection as an "identifier" (A User-Agent string, for example) can be generated by any other device capable of making a TCP connection.

From your comment:

> is there some kind of validation service, where we could check if the device token is an iphone ie the apple device id?

Even if there were ... you now simply have "security by obscurity"; All I need to do on any other device is send a valid id - you can not tell *what* is sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no - as others have said.

However, since

> the client side is an iphone application developed by us.

...you can ship a private key with that application, and hope nobody has enough incentive to bypass whatever security Apple has in place and reverse engineer your app to get their hands on that key.

(Note that this 'security' pattern has failed miserably for DVD encryption, console makers, etc... but if your app is confidential enough and the data you're protecting not worth much, it might be good enough for you).

Once you got that key, you can force authentication in your REST service based on some kind of challenge (initial request, 401 with challenge, client sign challenge with private key and send back with request repeat, server verifies with public key).

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpfull if you make a check of user agent in your code like this :

```
if(request.getHeader("User-Agent").indexOf("iphone") != -1){
        //Execute some code
   }
```

Comment: what if someone simulates a user agent on PC

Comment: Here comes the problem of mobile user agents, simulators and emulators sometimes face some problems in being detected as mobile user agents